# ViewPager with Google Map API v2 goes black

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-maps-v2

I have integrated the new google maps api v2 fragment in a view pager. When i move from the map tab(street view screen) to second tab(client detail), a black view shown instend of data into fragment. anyone know about solution.??

ScreenShot:

[image]

Code:

ListingStreetViewFragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_view, container, false);


        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // TODO handle this situation
        }

        markers = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        mMapView = (MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mMapView.onCreate(mBundle);
        mMapView.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded(inflatedView);

        return inflatedView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBundle = savedInstanceState;
    }

    // mapping between map object with xml layout.
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded(View inflatedView) {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());
                setUpMap();

            }
        }
    }

    //set location on map and show marker on random location
    private void setUpMap() {
            // random latitude and logitude

            // Adding a marker
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(53.558, 9.927))
                    .title("Hello Maps ");

            marker.snippet("dinet");



            // changing marker color

                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));


            mMap.addMarker(marker);

            // Move the camera to last position with a zoom level
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(53.558,
                                9.927)).zoom(16).build();

                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        if (null != mMapView)
            mMapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (null != mMapView)
            mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (null != mMapView)
            mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (null != mMapView)
            mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        if (null != mMapView)
            mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }
```

ListingClientDetailFragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.client_detail, container, false);

    initUi(rootView);
    idval = ListingListFragment.cid;
    System.out.println("SET: " + idval);
    setValues();

    return rootView;
}


protected void initUi(View v){
    db = new Databasehelper(getActivity());

    cDetail = new HashMap<String, String>();

    tvName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    tvType = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvType);
    tvStatus = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
    tvEmail = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
    tvPhone = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);

    ivCall = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivCall);
    ivMsg = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivMsg);

}

//get data from database and set into controls.
protected void setValues(){

    cDetail = db.getClientDetail(idval);
    tvName.setText(cDetail.get("name"));
    tvType.setText(cDetail.get("type"));
    tvStatus.setText(cDetail.get("status"));
    tvEmail.setText(cDetail.get("email"));
    tvPhone.setText(cDetail.get("phone"));

}
```

and there is no errors display in logcat. so, i cant trace it from there.

Comment: Please add some code or look at log cat this might be because of authentication error of api key.

Comment: @GrIsHu check it now..

Comment: @Rajiv look my code now..

Comment: @Segi You need to get the map using the `getMap()` method in your `onCreateView()` method of `ListingStreetViewFragment` class. Change the line as `mMapView = (MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.map).getMap();` Also do not need to call `oncreate()` and `onResume()`. It will be called automatically.

Comment: @GrIs i already tried using getMap(). still not worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i solved my problem with adding below code in **ListingStreetViewFragment.java** file after **inflaterView**:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
            frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
            ((ViewGroup) inflatedView).addView(frameLayout,
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem some time (four to five months, I believe) ago. I had a sliding menu opening from the left side of the screen, and a fragment with a map. When the map was showing, and I opened the menu, the actual map slided right, but the menu was covered by a black overlay that was clearly left there by the map somehow.

I think I have solved it thanks to some enlightened answer on a Stack Overflow question, but I cannot quite find it again. I'm not sure about it, though. Perhaps it was some comment on an Android bug report. For various reasons, I also lost the history of the repository that stored the code: I'm trying to reconstruct the solution by memory, so I won't bet it would nail the answer - perhaps it's just a hint towards a refined search you could do yourself to get closer to a much more informed source than myself.

However, here it goes: I think it was solved on the layout side. IIRC the trick was to add a view with a transparent background over the map. I already had an overlay view on the map, so on my part I just had to change the background color. The resulting XML file was something along these lines:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/map_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_button"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/menu_button_side"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_button_side"
            android:src="@drawable/red_menu_button"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The culprit was the background of some Open GL view that is used to render the map, which is black by default, or something. I believe this was really an Android bug report somewhere. So please try to overlay a layout or a view with a transparent background on your map, and see if that works. In my case, the ominious black cover disappeared, but it was still clearly visible under the map during the sliding animation of the menu. Anyway, that I considered only a glitch, and was satisfied enough with the result. I hope this helps somehow.

Comment: @Segi ...which is the Java equivalent of the XML I suggested. Glad to have helped.